# alert returns undefined (js)

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I am learning errors in js and I have came up with the following code:

```
function StartGame() {
  try {
   if (input.value == "") {throw alert("Complete blanks"); return false}
   if (!input.value.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)) {throw alert("Only letters allowed"); return false}
   if (input.value.length < 3) {throw alert("Must have at least 3 characters"); return false}}
   catch(errorAlert) {alert(errorAlert)}
  inputPanel.style.display = "none"

  ... //some code 
 }

let inputPanel = document.querySelector("#form")
let input = document.querySelector("#input") 

<form id="form" title="Write your name"> <label> Enter your username: </label>
   <input id="input" type="text" maxlength="10" autofocus>
   <button type="button" onclick="StartGame()" id="begin-game"> Submit </button>
  </form>
```

However, when throw event occurs (so when input is not properly submitted), first comes the alert (that is normal) ***BUT* then, another alert appears saying "undefined" and returns the rest of the code true (the rest of the code runs). Instead, I would like that when input is not properly validated, there are no undefined alerts and it returns false.** Any help please? Thanks

Comment: It's `throw Error` not `throw alert`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: ...I mean that you have written `throw alert` in your code. It should be `throw Error` instead.

Comment: Put the alert in your `catch` after you throw an error

Comment: I have actually taken as example this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_throw_error. In this code, throw is returned as a string... or maybe what you mean is that I shouldn't put alert on throw? (what I don't understand is that when yo say throw Error do you mean that "Error" should be a string)

Comment: @GuyIncognito - there is no reason why you cant throw an alert or anything else, but alert just returns undefined.

Comment: Why does alert returns udefined?

Comment: @Thomas - what would you prefer it to return?

Comment: I would like it to return the alert

Comment: Okay so throw only returns values?

Comment: Well actually I don't see the point of try, catch and throw because it can be skipped. Before, the code in my question didn't have try, catch and throw and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to throw the message and then alert it inside the catch block. When you put a function in an throw statement, the function will be executed and the return value will be thrown.

```js
try{
    // Do something that throws a message
    throw "Something messed up!";
}catch(message){
    // Alert the message here
    alert(message);
}
```

However, it's a much better idea to throw an `Error` object instead, as it contains helpful information for debugging purposes.

```js
try{
    // do something that throws an error
    throw new Error("Something screwed up!");
}catch(e){
    // alert the message here
    alert(e.message);
    // The error object also has other features 
    // that make it helpful for debugging, like the stack trace
    console.log(e.stack);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your `throw` keyword. Quoting MDN:

> The throw statement throws a user-defined exception. Execution of the
> current function will stop (the statements after throw won't be
> executed), and control will be passed to the first catch block in the
> call stack. If no catch block exists among caller functions, the
> program will terminate.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw).

Also as other users pointed out, you should throw an Error, not an alert